# Variable always 0 after affecting a value to it

Tags: javascript, algorithm, hashmap

I'm trying to create a hash map out of a string, the map is in this form :

```
{ 'char': charOccurrence }
```

This is my code :

```
function compress(text) {
  let hash = new Map();
  let prev = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
    let count = 0;
    prev.push(text[i]);
    for (let j = i+1; j < text.length; j++) {
      // if (prev.indexOf(text[j]) !== -1) break;
      if (text[i] === text[j]) {
        count += 1;
        console.log(count);
      }
    }
    hash.set(text[i], count);
  }
  console.log(hash);
}

compress('aaaaahhhheaaadeee');
```

The problem is `count` always 0, I don't know how this is possible even after affecting value in the for loop. This is what I get out of this code :

```
Map { 'a' => 0, 'h' => 0, 'e' => 0, 'd' => 0 }
```

What I'm missing here ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're overwriting the previous results.

Every time you see an "a", you start the count at 0 and read to the rest of the string and then *overwrite* whatever was in `hash` to be the total count you found. The last "a" in the string will get a total count of 0. This is what happens for every letter.

`prev`, which you're not doing anything with, was perhaps an attempt to prevent this from happening. (You could skip letters you've already counted.)

Here's a simpler (faster, too) method:

```
function compress(text) {
  let hash = new Map();
  for (let i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
    hash.set(text[i], (hash.get(text[i]) || 0) + 1);
  }
  return hash;
}

console.log(compress('aaaaahhhheaaadeee'));
// Map { 'a' => 8, 'h' => 4, 'e' => 4, 'd' => 1 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Note that you replace any existing instance of char:count pair by the last occurrence instance that has zero count (no more such char).

So make `hash.set` operation only for the first char occurrence - check for key existence **before** the second for-loop and execute that loop only when needed.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that at a certain point the count will be more than one, and will be written to the hash, but as you proceed further in the string, you will finally meet the last occurrence of some duplicate char, and start counting that character again, which now no longer occurs in the rest of the string, so you overwrite the hash entry with 0 at that point.

This happens for all characters: the last occurrence of each character makes you write 0 in the hash.

But I wonder why you use a `prev` array when the `Map` you already have is the best tool to manage the counting:

```js
function compress(chars) {
  return [...chars].reduce( (hash, c) => 
      hash.set(c, (hash.get(c) || 0) + 1),
      new Map
  );
}

var hash = compress('aaaaahhhheaaadeee');

console.log([...hash]);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```